# How to create if statement in foreach in php

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

How to create if function in foreach in php

I want something like this if(currency==id) script should exclude it

Here is the php code

```
<?php 
$curl = curl_init(); 
 
curl_setopt_array($curl, array( 
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.jobians.top/coinbase/accounts.php?api=N7696pIFgkF7vagl&key=AF3RO2AIrhuLpw40kyEUnZcc975dRfQq", 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "", 
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 2, 
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10, 
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true, 
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET" 
    )); 
$response = curl_exec($curl); 
 
curl_close($curl); 

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json2 = json_decode($response, true);

$id_array = array_map(function($el) { return $el['id']; }, $json2['data']);
$outputObject = [];
foreach ($json2['data'] as $el) {
    $outputObject[$el['id']] = $el['balance']['currency'];
}
echo json_encode( $outputObject );
?>
```

Comment: More information is likely needed. What is stopping you from writing this if statement inside your for loop?

Comment: I don't know where to place it, I'm new to php

Comment: You can write it in the for loop. Not exactly sure on what your trying to do though

Comment: @Reed how can I do it please give me example

Comment: How can I remove all id that same as currency from the script. Check image https://i.ibb.co/S7fvNVr/IMG-20220802-222216-726.jpg

Comment: You can use `unset`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You want to exclude all items that have the same id and currency.
- Each item in the result should have the keys 'id' and 'currency'.

You may use the functions `array_map` and `array_filter` to implement that.

```php
echo json_encode(
    array_map(
        function($item) {
            return [
                'id' => $item['id'],
                'currency' => $item['balance']['currency'],
            ];
        },
        array_filter(
            $json2['data'],
            function($item) {
                return $item['id'] !== $item['balance']['currency'];
            }
        ),
        []
    )
);
```

`array_filter` is used to return an array with only the items that follow the condition `$item['id'] !== $item['balance']['currency']`.

`array_map` is used to return an array with items that have the keys 'id' and 'currency'. There's a `[]` as the last argument because, [according to the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

> The returned array will preserve the keys of the array argument if and
> only if exactly one array is passed. If more than one array is passed,
> the returned array will have sequential integer keys.

If you want to preserve the keys, don't use `[]`. In that case, the output will be a JSON with numbers as strings like this:

```json
{"1":{"id":"B","currency":"C"}}
```

That was the [functional programming](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-functional-and-imperative-programming/) approach.

If you still want to use `foreach` and `if`, you need to declare another array to put there only the items you want:

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($json2['data'] as $item) {
    if ($item['id'] === $item['balance']['currency']) {
        continue;
    }
    $result [] = [
        'id' => $item['id'],
        'currency' => $item['balance']['currency'],
    ];
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically if you want to exclude from the list some specific currency, you should do something like:

```
$ignoredCurrency = 'DASH';

foreach ($json2['data'] as $el) {
    if($ignoredCurrency !== $el['balance']['currency']) {
        $outputObject[$el['id']] = $el['balance']['currency'];
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you have an array with currencies you want to exclude, it should go like this:

```
$ignoredCurrencies = ['DASH', 'USDC'];

foreach ($json2['data'] as $el) {
    if(!in_array($ignoredCurrencies, $el['balance']['currency'])) {
        $outputObject[$el['id']] = $el['balance']['currency'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I was to exclude Id that same as currency